# Непонятная формула и её результат

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, числа, системы-счисления

есть задача найти значение функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для неупорядоченного набора 128 битных чисел `Ak` каждый из которых представляется в виде

`Ak = 2^96 * a1k + 2^64 * a2k + 2^32 * a3k + 2^0 * a4k` ,

где

`0 <= aik <= 2^32 - 1`

а 
`log10(X)` – целая часть десятичного логарифма числа `X`,

и будем считать, что `log10(0) = 0`

а `N <= 5000`

**пример:**

```
2            // N - кол-во чисел этого набора
0 0 0 2324   // коеффициенты aik для текущего Ak
0 2332 0 0
```

значение суммы - 44

**Вопросы:**

1. Каким образом получилось 44 в этом примере ??
2. Что в данном контексте означает неупорядоченный набор чисел ?
3. Непонятно как происходит индексация в сумме - я так понимаю `k != j` ?? так как если бы было равно то какой смысл ксорить число с самим собой  ведь это даст `0` а логарифм от нуля тоже `0`

собственно, для этого примера у меня получилось следующее

```
    A0 - 0 0    0 2324
    A1 - 0 2332 0 0

    A0 XOR A1 = 0 2332 0 2324

    тогда X = 2^96*0 + 2^64+2332 + 2^32*0 + 2^0+2324 = 4.301780718×10²² 
    но отсюда log10(X) != 44
```

что я делаю не правильно ?

какой правильный алгоритм который выдал бы 44 ?

Comment: @RedHairOnMyHead  вы это к чему говорите ?  ну, в этой задаче мы полагаем что логарифм от нуля 0

Comment: Вспомнилось, "в военное время число пи может достигать четырех".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Должно получиться:

`A0 XOR A0`

`A0 XOR A1`

`A1 XOR A0`

`A1 XOR A1`

Первое и последнее, как вы уже заметили, равны нулю. А второе и третье равны между собой, следовательно то что вы нашли (22) нужно умножить на 2 и вы получите 44.

Comment: тоесть это двойная сумма выходит ?

Comment: Да, эту сумму можно расписать как двойную

Comment: просто раз один знак сигмы то как-то не очень не интиутивно предпологать что тут на самом деле двойная сумма.