# оптимизировать вычисления

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, производительность

при реализации этой [задачи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668830/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82) столкнулся с проблемой медленных вычислений

Сперва решил ускорить `log10` - не помогло, хоть и вычисляет быстрее чем `log10` из стандартной библиотеки - (см. сравнение в коцне вопроса), но использование таблицы степеней 10 оказалось не сильно хорошей идей, хотя бин поиск должен был повлиять...

Вобщем, не могу понять что ещё и главное как можно оптимизировать кроме вычисления десятичного логарифма

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const long double _10_POWERS[40] = 
{
    1e+0,  1e+1,  1e+2,  1e+3,  1e+4,  1e+5,  1e+6,  1e+7,  1e+9,  1e+10,
    1e+11, 1e+12, 1e+13, 1e+13, 1e+14, 1e+15, 1e+16, 1e+17, 1e+18, 1e+19,
    1e+20, 1e+21, 1e+22, 1e+23, 1e+24, 1e+25, 1e+26, 1e+27, 1e+28, 1e+29,
    1e+30, 1e+31, 1e+32, 1e+33, 1e+34, 1e+35, 1e+36, 1e+37, 1e+38, 1e+39
};    

static inline uint32_t log10_fast(long double x) 
{
    //uint32_t res = 0;    
    int l = 0, r = 40 - 1;

    while (l <= r)
    {
        int mid = l + ((r -l) >> 1);

        if ( x >= _10_POWERS[mid] && x < _10_POWERS[mid + 1] )
        {   return mid; }   

        if (x >= _10_POWERS[mid])
            l = mid;
        else
            r = mid;
    }

    return 0;
};


uint32_t compute(int n, std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>>& a)
{
    long double x = 0.0f;
    uint32_t s = 0;

    const long double _2_96 = pow(2, 96);
    const long double _2_64 = pow(2, 64);
    const long double _2_32 = pow(2, 32);    

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        {                       
            x =  _2_96 * (a[i][0] ^ a[j][0]);
            x += _2_64 * (a[i][1] ^ a[j][1]);
            x += _2_32 * (a[i][2] ^ a[j][2]);
            x += (a[i][3] ^ a[j][3]);

            s += log10_fast(x);
        }    
    }

    return 2 * s;
}    

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{     
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>> a(n, std::vector<uint32_t>(4));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            std::cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }    
    std::cout << compute(n, a) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Какие есть идеи по поводу оптимизаций тут ?

Может есть другой более быстрый способ вычислить `log10` ? Или может дело не в логарифме ?

*p.s.*

сравнение `log10` и `log10_fast`

```
uint32_t s = 0;
high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1e+8; ++i)
{
    s += log10( static_cast<long double>(rand()) );
}     
high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
duration<double> dur = duration_cast<milliseconds>( t2 - t1 );
std::cout << dur.count() << '\n';  // 6.374 sec


s = 0;
t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1e+8; ++i)
{
    s += log10_fast( static_cast<long double>(rand()) );
}    
t2 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
dur = duration_cast<milliseconds>( t2 - t1 );
std::cout << dur.count() << '\n'; // 5.907 sec
```

Comment: Меня терзают смутные сомнения насчет точности вычислений... Ведь может же быть такой вариант, что число окажется больше/меньше границы, а принято будет как граничное...

Comment: @Harry больше меньше какой границы ? если речь о числе `x` то во всяком случае точность, я думаю, что здесь не принципиальна так как логарифм должен давать одно и тоже число для целого набора чисел например лежащих в диапазоне `10^5 до 99^5` - число 5, а что касается быстроты операций с целыми числами над числами с плавающей точкой то тут да, понятно быстрее, но это уже другой вопрос

Comment: Ну сами подумайте - представим, что у вас в битах - ровно в какой-то там степени. Вы уверены, что логарифм не вернет значение на 1 меньше, например?...

Comment: @Harry это зависит в какую сторону округлять я думаю, мне непонятна какая тут связь между точностями вычислений и производительностью ?

Comment: @Harry во всяком случае с моими "не точными вычислениями" неправильных результатов я не увидел запуская это решение на сайте

Comment: Я не о производительности! Я о самом методе решения через плавающую точку.

Comment: @ampawd, если не секрет, откуда задача, что пришлось оптимизировать? При `n=5000` ваше решение у меня работает меньше секунды.

Comment: @Дмитрий ну это смотря на каком железе запускать ))

Comment: @Дмитрий меньше секунды это с использованием `log10_fast` ?

Comment: Вы ведь с `-O3` компилировали? Без `-O3` у меня работало 10 секунд, в принципе тоже не долго. Или у вас непрерывно приходят массивы чисел, и вам нужно быстро отвечать?

Comment: @ampawd, да, с log10_fast

Comment: @Дмитрий без этого флага, а числа не непрерывно приходят, а все разом

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59112/discussion-between--and-ampawd).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне кажется, что главная проблема заключается в том, что вы много раз вызываете функцию `log10`. Давайте распишем сумму логарифмов как логарифм произведения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если чисел немного, так что их произведение не вызовет переполнение, то можно так и посчитать.

Другая проблема заключается в использовании дробных чисел, они не так быстро перемножаются, как целые. Хочу предложить приближённое решение в целых числах. Заметим, что если, например, `a[i][1] xor a[j][1]` не равно нулю, то `a[i][3] xor a[j][3]` и `a[i][4] xor a[j][4]` можно не считать, так как их добавка к xor'у будет очень маленькой. Рассмотрим следующий алгоритм:

1. Для каждой пары `(i, j)`, приближённо считаем `A_i xor A_j` в виде `x * 2^k`, где `x, k` --- некоторые целые числа, причём `0 <= x < 2^32`.
2. Перемножаем полученные значения следующим образом: `(x1 * 2^k1) * (x2 * 2^k2) = (x1 * x2) * 2^(k1+k2) = x * 2^(k1+k2)`, причём `0 <= x <= 2^64`. Представляем `x` в виде `x=y * 2^m'`, причём `0 <= y < 2^32`. Итак, `(x1 * 2^k1) * (x2 * 2^k2) = y * 2^(k1+k2+m)`
3. По факту мы посчитали не десятичный логарифм, а двоичный, чтобы получить десятичный логарифм, нужно домножить на log_10(2).

Собственно, код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include "/home/dima/C++/debug.h"
using namespace std;

double compute(const vector<uint64_t[2]> &a) {
    static const uint64_t two_power_32 = 1ull << 32;
    int n = a.size();

//  текущий накопленный результат равен value * 2^power_index
    uint64_t value = 1;
    int power_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            uint64_t xor1 = a[i][0] ^a[j][0];
            uint64_t xor2 = a[i][1] ^a[j][1];

            uint64_t value_current;
            if (xor1 == 0) {
                value_current = xor2;
            } else if (xor1 >= two_power_32) {
                value_current = xor1;
                power_index += 64;
            } else {
                assert(0 <= xor1 && xor1 < two_power_32);
                value_current = (xor1 << 32) + (xor2 >> 32);
                power_index += 32;
            }
            while (value_current >= two_power_32) {
                value_current /= 2;
                ++power_index;
            }
            assert(0 <= value_current && value_current < two_power_32);
            assert(0 <= value && value < two_power_32);
            value *= value_current;
            while (value >= two_power_32) {
                value /= 2;
                ++power_index;
            }
        }
    }

//  result = log10(value * 2^power_index)
//  result = log10(value) + log10(2^power_index)
//  result = log10(value) + power_index * log10(2)
    double result = log10(value) + power_index * log10(2);
    return result * 2;
}

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<uint64_t[2]> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            uint32_t ai1, ai2;
            cin >> ai1 >> ai2;
            a[i][j] = (uint64_t(ai1) << 32) + ai2;
        }
    }
    cout << compute(a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

К сожалению, я не сравнивал производительность, но я искренне верю, что это работает быстрее, чем `n^2` раз вычислять `log10`.

**Обновление:** я тут потестировал, при `n=5000` моя реализация чуть медленнее вашей оригинальной. Всё дело в этих циклах:

```
while (value >= two_power_32) {
    value /= 2;
    ++power_index;
}
```

Их можно переписать разными способами, вот вариант для GCC:

```
static const uint64_t two_power_32 = 1ull << 32;

inline void divide_until_less_then_two_power_32(uint64_t &value, int &power_index) {
//  Эта функция эквивалентна этим строчкам:
//  while (value >= two_power_32) {
//      value /= 2;
//      ++power_index;
//  }

    if (value < two_power_32) {
        return;
    }
    int power_index_delta = 32 - __builtin_clzll(value);
    power_index += power_index_delta;
    value >>= power_index_delta;
    assert(0 <= value && value < two_power_32);
}
```

Полный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#include "/home/dima/C++/debug.h"

static const uint64_t two_power_32 = 1ull << 32;

inline void divide_until_less_then_two_power_32(uint64_t &value, int &power_index) {
//  Эта функция эквивалентна этим строчкам:
//  while (value >= two_power_32) {
//      value /= 2;
//      ++power_index;
//  }

    if (value < two_power_32) {
        return;
    }
    int power_index_delta = 32 - __builtin_clzll(value);
    power_index += power_index_delta;
    value >>= power_index_delta;
    assert(0 <= value && value < two_power_32);
}

double compute(const vector<uint64_t[2]> &a) {
    int n = a.size();

//  текущий накопленный результат равен value * 2^power_index
    uint64_t value = 1;
    int power_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            uint64_t xor1 = a[i][0] ^a[j][0];
            uint64_t xor2 = a[i][1] ^a[j][1];

            uint64_t value_current;
            if (xor1 == 0) {
                value_current = xor2;
            } else if (xor1 >= two_power_32) {
                value_current = xor1;
                power_index += 64;
            } else {
                assert(0 <= xor1 && xor1 < two_power_32);
                value_current = (xor1 << 32) + (xor2 >> 32);
                power_index += 32;
            }
            divide_until_less_then_two_power_32(value_current, power_index);
            assert(0 <= value_current && value_current < two_power_32);
            assert(0 <= value && value < two_power_32);
            value *= value_current;
            divide_until_less_then_two_power_32(value, power_index);
        }
    }

//  result = log10(value * 2^power_index)
//  result = log10(value) + log10(2^power_index)
//  result = log10(value) + power_index * log10(2)
    double result = log10(value) + power_index * log10(2);
    return result * 2;
}

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<uint64_t[2]> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            uint32_t ai1, ai2;
            cin >> ai1 >> ai2;
            a[i][j] = (uint64_t(ai1) << 32) + ai2;
        }
    }
    cout << compute(a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если я всё правильно посчитал, то эта версия работает в два раза быстрее.

**Обновление 2:** исправил ошибку (добавил строчку `power_index += 32;`)

Comment: Произведение может запросто нарушить точность. Впрочем, поскольку ее нет и в исходном решении, то...

Comment: идеи, конечно хорошие, касательно оптимизаций, но вот запуская последний ваш вариант почему то выдаётся 26.0014
, когда правильный ответ 22 для теста `2
0 0 0 2324
0 2332 0 0`

Comment: @ampawd, да, в ответе действительно была ошибка. Я исправил, теперь на этом тесте результат 45.2673, что очень близко к [правильному ответу](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*log10(2332*2**64%2B2324)), который, кстати не равен 44.

Comment: 44 будет если брать целочисленное значение логарифма округлённое вниз и умноженное на 2 поэтому это тоже верный ответ, а там  вещественный логарифм считается

Comment: спасибо за идеи, старание

Comment: Действительно, там же целая часть, не заметил. Тогда воспользуйтесь [другим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669025/227016) товарищ @Harry дело говорит.

Answer (score 4):

У меня не готовый код, но...

Я бы делал так - как минимум для повышения точности (потому что ваш `double` никак не отловит точное значение, например, того же 10<sup>39</sup>). Сделал бы 128-разрядное число - как

```
unsigned long a[4];
```

Далее, вот такую табличку степеней 10 в таком **точном** представлении -

```
unsigned long p10[39][4] =
{
    { 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000 },   // 1
    { 0x0000000a, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000 },   // 10
    { 0x00000064, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000 },   // 100
    { 0x000003e8, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000 },   // 1000
    { 0x00002710, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000 },   // 10000
    { 0x000186a0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000 },   // 100000
    ...
    { 0x00000000, 0x098a2240, 0x5a86c47a, 0x4b3b4ca8 },   // 10000000000....0
    { 0x00000000, 0x5f655680, 0x8943acc4, 0xf050fe93 },   // 10000000000....00
```

(полностью - здесь: http://vpaste.net/RljZF). Ну, или если удобнее - то наоборот, от старшего к младшему. Далее я бы написал простую функцию сравнения вот таких 128-разрядных чисел - очень просто, начиная со старшего - и вперед...

И логарифмировал бы без всяких переводов в `double`ы - аналогично вашему поиску при взятии логарифма. Причем надо еще померить, дает ли что-то при таком небольшом количестве бинарный поиск или нет. Можно поиграться, начиная с поиска по старшему элементу. При несовпадении - сразу определяется логарифм, при совпадении - переходим к следующему и так далее... Написать у вас, я думаю, проблем не составит.

Плюсы - **точность**, не используется арифметика с плавающей точкой.

**Update о точности...**

Рассмотрим значение  `0x00000000 0x00000000  0x00038d7e  0xa4c67FFE`, т.е. число 999999999999998.

Очевидно, что значение его логарифма, `floor` до целого - 14.

Теперь вычисляем ваше значение -

```
double x = pow(2,32)*0x00038d7e + 0xa4c67FFE;
```

VC++ 2015 дает для

```
double x = pow(2,32)*0x00038d7e + 0xa4c67FFE;
printf("%.10lf\n",x);
printf("%.10lf\n",log10(x));
int l = log10(x);
printf("%d\n",l);
```

следующие результаты:

```
999999999999998.0000000000
15.0000000000
15
```

Вы можете возразить, что логарифм вы считаете не так... но проверьте сами, что число 
`0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0DE0B6B3 0xA763FFF8` - т.е. 999999999999999992 - даст при вычислении вашим способом - с умножением на `pow(2,...)` - число

```
double x == 1000000000000000000.00000
```

Так что значения логарифмов у вас все равно для некоторых чисел окажутся неверными.

Comment: на самом деле я уже решил проблему, дело было в функции `log10_fast` там цикл зацикливался когда `x == 0` отсюда и тормоза бесконечные - так то эта функция значительно повысила производительность, на серверах этих всего 0.358 сек, а с стардартным `log10` по времени вылетало, но что-то мне подсказывает что если использоваться вашу таблицу можно ещё выиграть во времени :)

Comment: @ampawd Еще раз - главное, что оно обеспечит **ТОЧНОСТЬ** - см. мой дополненный ответ: в нем конкретные примеры неприятностей. То, что вы на них в своих расчетах не попадали - не моя вина :)

Comment: ну такое возможно да, не спорю