# Можно ли оценить результаты произведения больших чисел не вычисляя их напрямую?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, олимпиада, длинная-арифметика

В олимпиадной задаче для 7-8 классов используются числа порядка `10^18`. Сами числа укладываются в диапазон `long long (_int64)`. В процессе решения приходится перемножать два числа подобных размеров и сравнивать подобные произведения друг с другом.

То есть, результатом произведения могут быть числа порядка `10^36`, и эти результаты нужно между собой сравнить. Учитывая, что это олимпиада, не думаю, что там разрешается использование сторонних библиотек для работы с большими числами, а судя по возрасту участников, вряд ли им самим нужно писать функции для работы с большими числами.

Можно ли оценить результаты произведений, не вычисляя из напрямую, и сравнить между собой?

UPD. 
По просьбе `Alexey Ten` приложил скан задачи.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В зависимости от задачи может быть проще вместо `a*b и c*d` сравнивать `a/d и c/b` или ещё что-то.

Comment: @MBo учитывая, что эти числа по условию задачи могут иметь значения в диапазоне от 1 до 10^18, то думаю, да, можно и так. Спасибо.

Comment: Покажите задачку. Возможно как раз одна из «фишек» этой задачи это придумать решение не требующее перемножения больших чисел

Comment: @Alexey приложил скан задачи к посту

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно сравнить `a1 * a2` и `b1 * b2`
Сравниваем целую часть, а если они равны, то остаток от деления на `a2 * b2`
Пользуемся тем, что (a * b) % (c * b) = (a % c) * b

```
int cmp(uint64 a1, uint64 a2, uint64 b1, uint64 b2) {
    if (a1 < a2) {
        std::swap(a1, a2);
    } 
    if (b1 < b2) {
        std::swap(b1, b2);
    } 

    if (a2 == 0 && b2 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    If (a2 == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (b2 == 0) {
        return 1;
    } 

    auto div1 = a1 / b2;
    auto div2 = b1 / a2;
    if (div1 > div2) {
        return 1;
    } 
    if (div1 < div2) {
        return -1;
    }  
    return cmp(a1 % b2, a2, b1 % a2, b2);
}
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. Нужно делить на произведение меньших множителей. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Добавил деление на 0.

Comment: работает. Спасибо огромное. Единственно, я бы заменил эту строку `if (a2 == 0 && b2 == 0) return 0;` на эту `if ((a2 == 0 && b2 == 0) || (a1 == b1 && a2 == b2)) return 0;`

Comment: Вот непонятно, ведь при перестановке переменных в начале функции нарушается тождество `(a * b) % (c * b) = (a % c) * b`. Почему работает?

Comment: 1) Это уже детали. Работать и так и так будет. 2) Тождество не нарушается. От перестановки множителей произведение не меняется. `(a % c) * b == b * (a % c)`

Answer (score 2):

Для таких оценок обычно существует (монотонно возрастающая) функция логарифм. И ее свойство

```
log(ab) = log(a) + log(b)
```

Монотонное возрастание говорит о том, что если

```
log(a) > log(b)
```

то и

```
a > b
```

(лишь бы основание логарифма было больше 1).

Минусы - все же это числа с плавающей точкой, а значит - есть вопросы точности, и если только `ab` и `cd` *очень* близки - логарифм может дать не совсем точный ответ. В таком случае лучше все же делать 128-битное умножение, оно реально очень простое.

P.S. Не совсем в тему, но вот пару вопросов, в которых используются логарифмы для больших значений и которые могут вам помочь в понимании: [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707292/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) и [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668981/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

P.P.S. И, кстати, написать 128-битное сложение/вычитание/умножение довольно-таки просто (деление посложнее, но оно вроде по условию не требуется).

P.P.P.S. Не уверен, в каком классе изучают логарифмы - но если человек идет на олимпиаду, у него всяко знаний должно быть побольше обычных школьных.

Comment: Вы правы, проблема точности присутствует, если взять достаточно большие величины. Например, для величин `long long a = 1e18` и `long long b = a+1` значение логарифма одинаковое и равно 41.446531673892821.